# After executing stored procedure from ASP.NET C# all labels or alert messages are not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I really need help, I've been searching this for days. I faced an odd problem.

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 that have all calculation for update all my transaction table.

`@tmpsku` is the product, if I pass some product code here it will only process this product.

If I run the stored procedure for 1 product only, it works well. The message show and the alert work well, both in ssms and asp.net (only take 2-5 seconds).

**But the problems occur** when I didn't pass any value to `@tmpsku` which means I want to calculate for all products; that take more time (1-2 minutes both in ssms and asp.net)

When I execute it right in query analyzer its work well under 2 minutes (we update around 10 table that have 100000 over data)

But when I execute the stored procedure from my program, it won't stop, and the message won't show, both label or alert message but the odd things is that all the process in stored procedure finishes (all table updated).

This is the code-behind:

```
try
{
    string ctempdate1 = txtFirstDate.Text.ToString().Split('-')[1] + "-" + txtFirstDate.Text.ToString().Split('-')[0] + "-" + txtFirstDate.Text.ToString().Split('-')[2];
    string ctempdate2 = txtLastDate.Text.ToString().Split('-')[1] + "-" + txtLastDate.Text.ToString().Split('-')[0] + "-" + txtLastDate.Text.ToString().Split('-')[2];
    string cBrandCode = Session["Brand"].ToString();
    string cUserId = Session["UserId"].ToString();
    string cSKUNo = txtMarinatedSkuNo.Text;

    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateMAC", conn1))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter", 0);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", ctempdate1.ToString().Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateend", ctempdate2.ToString().Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@session", cBrandCode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tmpsku", cSKUNo.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", cUserId);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@output", SqlDbType.Int, 30);
            cmd.Parameters["@output"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@fsid", SqlDbType.Int, 30);
            cmd.Parameters["@fsid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ftsid", SqlDbType.Int, 30);
            cmd.Parameters["@ftsid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@fwhih", SqlDbType.Int, 30);
            cmd.Parameters["@fwhih"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@fwhid", SqlDbType.Int, 30);
            cmd.Parameters["@fwhid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@fwhs", SqlDbType.Int, 30);
            cmd.Parameters["@fwhs"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.CommandTimeout = 1200;

            conn1.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn1.Close();

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            tmprows = cmd.Parameters["@output"].Value.ToString();
            cwhid = cmd.Parameters["@fwhid"].Value.ToString();
            cwhih = cmd.Parameters["@fwhih"].Value.ToString();
            ctsid = cmd.Parameters["@ftsid"].Value.ToString();
            csid = cmd.Parameters["@fsid"].Value.ToString();
            cwhs = cmd.Parameters["@fwhs"].Value.ToString();
        }

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Record Inserted Successfully')", true);

        LblMsg.Text = "Update Successful with '"+ tmprows +" records ";
    }
}
catch (TimeoutException ex)
{
    libsx.LogError(ex);
    LblMsg.Text = "Update Failed";
}
```

I've been searching and trying many way to resolve this. Some say that it might parameter sniffing issue:

- I've tried to `SET ARITHABORT ON`
- Clean the cache with `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`

This part of the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateMAC]
    (@Parameter int,
     @date date , 
     @dateend date , 
     @session varchar(5) ,
     @tmpsku varchar(50) = '' ,
     @userid varchar(50),
     @output int output,
     @fsid int,
     @ftsid int ,
     @fwhih int ,
     @fwhid int ,
     @fwhs int)
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @vParameter int
    declare @vdate date 
    declare @vdateend date 
    declare @vsession varchar(5)
    declare @vtmpsku varchar(50) 
    declare @vuserid varchar(50)
    declare @fsid int
    declare @ftsid int 
    declare @fwhih int 
    declare @fwhid int 
    declare @fwhs int 

    set @vParameter = @Parameter
    set @vdate = @date
    set @vdateend = @dateend
    set @vsession = @session
    set @vtmpsku = @tmpsku
    set @vuserid = @userid
    set @vfsid = @fsid
    set @vftsid = @ftsid
    set @vfwhih = @fwhih
    set @vfwhs = @fwhs
```

- Use Local Parameter in the stored procedure
- Use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` in which query that take time
- Create the stored procedure with `WITH RECOMPILE AS`

But none of that change anything.

If you have any suggestion of what the real problem is or the advice for this issue, I'll really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Two things you can do. Set up a profiler trace on the proc and see what it's actually doing when called from the app. The second thing you can do, which is kind of a hack, is if you know which statement it's hanging on, you can try putting `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` so you don't have the parameter sniffing issue.

Comment: @Xedni sadly,I dont have sql profiler